# boost:asio receiving data from client

Tags: c++, tcp, boost-asio

Here's my problem: client connects to server via tcp-socket, server accepts this connection, then client sends some data to server in random periods of time, how should server knows when to read data from client. In other words is there some kind of listener on data receiving?

Comment: What does the protocol dictate?

Comment: I suppose nothing, do you have solution for another protocol?

Comment: yes, figure out the protocol used between your client and server. Is it a fixed length header? Perhaps delineated by a new line character? Something else entirely?

Comment: For example, it's just a digit [0...3]

Answer (score 1):

In general the server should always be waiting for data on each connection - i.e. when processing a request from the client, the server should immediately start another async_read request on that connection to wait for the next request (and once the server has received a complete request, that request gets processed and so on).